# Remove First images from feed content

Tags: wordpress, feed

I want to show only text and don't want to show images. Notable that, I don't want to remove img attribute.

How can I do this? I've tried:

```
<img class="pagehead" src="/graphics/magazine/307/1.jpg" alt="" />

function remove_first_image ($content) {
    if (is_feed()) {
        $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content, 1);
    } 
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content_rss', 'remove_first_image');
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_first_image');
```

But its not working for me.

Comment: Define 'not working': causes errors? truncates HTML so that it is no longer valid?
You may want to replace `<img ` with `<input type="hidden" `to that the code remains valid

Comment: Consider using `the_excerpt_rss` instead of `the_content_rss` which is depricated.

Comment: Please try this script. This is not tested but hope will work for you.

Comment: @nicolas-cami i do that and same problem

Comment: @nicolallias i dont knew what you talking about !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this script. This is not tested but hope will work for you.

```
function remove_first_image ($content) {
      if (!is_page() && !is_feed() && !is_feed() && !is_home()) {
        $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content, 1);
      } 
    return $content;
    }
    add_filter('the_content', 'remove_first_image');
```

or see this link  http://www.wpworking.com/hacks-2/remove-first-image-from-wordpress-post/

This script will search the content and remove the first image from your posts. Here  `preg_replace()` function searches for the image tag and removes the first occurrence from the content.

Comment: Please try this script. This is not tested but hope will work for you.

Comment: @JordanLeigh, what issue, you are facing?

Comment: its must remove first img tag ,,  but your code dont do that

Comment: Please see this link http://www.wpworking.com/hacks-2/remove-first-image-from-wordpress-post/

Comment: @JordanLeigh, I am glad to help you.